# How can I insert logs just in test environment in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, logging

I want to put some code ONLY in test environment, for example insert a line of log:

```
puts "Something in TEST"
```

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: `puts "Something in TEST" if Rails.env.test?`

Comment: Why? Logging just in tests seems weird to me.

Comment: @DaveNewton I just have this as an example. Not good to put the real code here.

Comment: I'm not asking for an example, I'm asking why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Rails 2.x,  the best way to get the current environment was using `RAILS_ENV`. Rails 2.x or later, Rails introduced the `Rails` module with method `Rails.env`. So you can use

> Before 2.x:  `if RAILS_ENV == 'test'`
>
> After 2.x:  `if Rails.env.test?`